# Return method values are not displaying in webpart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

we are working with a SPFX webpart, pulling SP site Lists and list template.
please tack a look the output we are getting

[image]

Here is the piece of code to the above output.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
return (
<div>
  <ol>
    {    
        this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
        return(
        <li>
        <span>{mylists.Title}</span> &emsp; <span>{mylists.BaseTemplate}</span>
        </li>);
      })
    }
    </ol>
</div>
);
```

}

here actual issue is List template is returns as number,
so each List template number has friendly names like 100=Custom List , 101= Document Lib etc..
here is the **[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf)** to display list of templates with friendly names.

so we have created a TS file in the Component solution to with all template number with friendly names. imported the list template file in to TSX file.

We tried to modify the above code to get friendly name using the base template number return method is not returning any values.
Please see the blow code.

```
<ol>
    {    
        this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
          listtempates.filter((a:any) =>{
          if(a.Code === mylists.BaseTemplate)
          {
          return(
        <li>
        <span>{mylists.Title}</span> &emsp; <span>{a.Code}</span>
        </li>)}});
      })
    }
    </ol>
```

[image]

I added console.log() in the if condition to check if condition is executing or not till the if its working but inside return its not working.

```
if(a.Code === mylists.BaseTemplate)
          {
            console.log("Condition Test is executed or not");
          
          return(
        <li>
        <span>{mylists.Title}</span> &emsp; <span>{a.Code}</span>
        </li>)}})
```

[image]

what is the issue here how to resolve the issue here but make sure we have to refer/import the file to lookup the friendly names from base number.

any assistance please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find below answer

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
const listItems = this.state.sitecontents.map(function (myLists) {
  let items;

  if (myLists.BaseTemplate) {
    for (let i of listTempates) {
      if (i['Code'] == myLists.BaseTemplate) {
        items = (
          <li key={i['Code']}>
            <span>
              {myLists.Title}&nbsp;{i.Template}
            </span>
          </li>
        );
      }
    }
  }

  return items;
});

return (
  <div>
    <ol>{listItems}</ol>
  </div>
);
}
```

Your Template items should be like below

```
export const listTempates = [
  {
    Template: 'Custom List',
    Code: 100,
  },
  {
    Template: 'List1',
    Code: 101,
  },
  {
    Template: 'List2',
    Code: 102,
  },
];
```

Comment: Really appreciate, this piece of code is working like charm, that is what I am looking actually. its helps me a lot Sayyed Thank you very much.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the items to render here:

```
this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
```

In the first fragment, you need to `return` something from the function. In the first fragment, you do, but in the second fragment, you do not return anything from the function used in `map`. Therefore, you get an empty result.

You could try using `find` instead of filter, somewhat like this (:

```
/// assuming you have a definition like:
const listtempates = [
 { Code: 101, Name: "Document Library" },
 { .... }
];

this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey) {
  const found = listtempates.find(a => a.Code === mylists.BaseTemplate);
  return (
    <li>
      <span>{mylists.Title}</span> &emsp; <span>{found.Name}</span>
    </li>)
   );
})
```

Comment: if you see Map function is there already, can you please help me here to update on how can I write the code ? make sure i want to get the List Title and respective friendly name using(reference ) base template

Comment: just want to know, its already returning List Titles and Base template number, I think second fragment is for any Key, Can you please assist here how can i check if condition to get friendly name instead of Base Number please ?

Comment: error like... Property **find** is not doesn`t exist on type here is the complete error "Property 'find' does not exist on type '{ Template: string; Code: number; }[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option"

Comment: I've added the definition of what I assumed to be the lookup (I assumed it's an array). You have not shown your version of the "listtemplates" so I was not sure what it was.

Comment: `export const listtempates = [
{
"Template": "Custom List", "Code": 100,
}
]` Here is the peice of code where i am created for lookup friendly names with reference of Basetemplate code 
Please assist me if file need to update in a specific format

Comment: If you don't have "find" for arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find (use Internet Explorer for example), you could replace it with `.filter(...)[0]`